# How to upload base64 image to GCloud Storage

Tags: python, base64, storage, gcloud

How do you upload an image from your web to gcloud Storage?

- **client**: React app
- **server**: Python(Flask)

**CLIENT SIDE**: I have a file browse component where I choose an image from the local drive. Then, I transform the image into a base64 string, and send it to the server.

**SERVER-SIDE**: 
Then I upload the base64 image: `blob.upload_from_string(base64data, type="image/jpeg")`

But when I look inside my bucket I see a 1 black pixel image.

### Questions

- Can I upload a base64 image right into my bucket?
- Why does my image is being procced as a black pixel? where does it break?

Comment: Are you using `content_type`? https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.0/storage-blobs.html#gcloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_string

Comment: yes, I use FileReader API and get the base64 string, and its type, which  I pass as the content_type

Comment: I suspect the issue is that the method is not decoding the string on receipt and so GCS receives bytes corresponding to the encoded string and the content-type.

Comment: I've been having the same issue. Setting the content_type to image/png is what makes the file appear as a tiny empty square. Otherwise, the file is just the base64 string. One solution is to save the base64 string as an image file locally on your api server, send it off to GCP, then delete the file, but that's far from good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end what i did was to remove the first part of the string `data:image/jpeg;base64,`, (of course its not necessarily a jpeg.. its just an example).
I decoded  the rest of the string back to an image, and passed the content_type also.

That solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem, this is what I did

```
import base64, re

bucket = storage.bucket()
blob = bucket.blob(path)
regex = r"(?<=data:)(.*)(?=;)"
split = image.split('base64')
format_image = re.findall(regex, split[0])[0]
base64_image = base64.b64decode(split[1])
blob.upload_from_string(base64_image, content_type=format_image)
# Opt : if you want to make public access from the URL
blob.make_public()
```